# Error in connecting to EC2 hosted rails server from kotlin android app using okHttp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kotlin, amazon-ec2, okhttp

I am deployed my rails server on EC2 instance and I am trying to get data from server using http requests (for that I am using [okHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/). But I am facing some connection issue in some devices. I tried finding out the issue but still unable to do it.

kotlin code:

```
val client = OkHttpClient()
val body = FormBody.Builder().build()

// to create url I am using server IP directly without any port
val urlNetworkCheck = Constants.URL_CHECK_NETWORK_CONNECTION // http://10.40.21.16/api/v1/check_network
val requestNetworkCheck = Request.Builder().url(urlNetworkCheck).post(body).build()

client.newCall(requestNetworkCheck).enqueue(object: Callback {
    override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
         val responseNetworkCheck = response.body?.string()
         logger.info { "Network connection is present." }
    }

    override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
        logger.info { "Could not connect to server. Exception: " + e.message }
        runOnUiThread {
            showToast(Constants.TOAST_NETWORK_ERROR)
        }
    }
})
```

On many devices, TOAST_NETWORK_ERROR is being shown. Please let me know what could be wrong here.

Update: Exception: CLEARTEXT communication to 18.224.2.107 not permitted by network security policy is what I am getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like **Android P doesn't allow non-HTTP connections by default**.

If your server doesn't support HTTPs, seems like you can enable it specifically according to this article: http://www.douevencode.com/articles/2018-07/cleartext-communication-not-permitted/

Or even this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50834600/976880

Comment: Adding android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in AndroidManifest.xml fiile worked.